# bash script to make `tail -f` exit when the file is moved or deleted

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix

Currently removing, moving or renaming a file that has `tail -f` running on it does nothing, and I'd like it to abort. I've read the man pages and it seems that -f should abort on file move and that -F will follow the file but on Mac OS X it seems -f and -F are the same. How can I write a bash script that makes tail -f exit cleanly after the file has been moved?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO but checking the man page it would appear you have it backwards https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tail.1.html but in addition, `-F` will then tail a new file created in the same location with the same name.

Comment: The man pages say -F will additionally follow the file if it has been renamed. Comically -f will do this as well.

Comment: What is the on-topic place for this? Is bash not a programming language?

Comment: superuser.stackexchange.com or possibly apple.stackexchange.com ; SO is specific to programming problems ... you're asking about the use/behavior of an OS command.

Comment: I just figured it out while surfing SO for `tail -f` related questions.

Comment: The original question per se was a little off-topic, but the _answer_ requires [bash] programming - edited to reflect that.

Comment: @schellsan: It's true that on **OSX** both `-f` and `-F` follow the file after it's renamed, but `-F` does something that `-f` doesn't: should a file under the _original_ name reappear, *it* will be tailed *again* from then on. On **Linux**, the behavior of `-F` is more intuitive: if the original file is renamed, tailing is suspended with an error message - until a [new] file under the original name reappears. That said, to achieve what you want, you do need a programmatic solution, as provided in your own answer; see also mine.

Comment: I really don't see why the minutiae of shell programming are off topic for SO.  Shell programming is *programming* and getting answers to programming questions is what SO is for.

Comment: @mklement0, Thanks, that's the explanation I needed.

Comment: @jonathan-leffler , I agree - I'm writing a bash script and needed this as a part of it so it seemed very on topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- On **Linux**, you can use  `tail --follow=name` (rather than just `-f`, which is equivalent to `--follow=descriptor`) to achieve what you want, but ONLY if the file is DELETED rather than moved - once the file is deleted, an error message is reported and `tail` exits (with code 1); sadly, by contrast, if the file is merely MOVED (renamed), `tail` does NOT exit - necessitating a programmatic solution.
- On **OSX**, you always need a *programmatic solution* - whether the file is moved or deleted.

**bash script** for exiting tailing once the target file no longer exists (under its original name) - more robust formulations of the script from @schellsan's own answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tail -f "$1" &  # start tailing in the background
while [[ -f $1 ]]; do sleep 0.1; done # periodically check if target still exists
kill $! 2>/dev/null || : # kill tailing process, ignoring errors if already dead
```

- Deals correctly with filenames that need quoting (e.g., names with embedded spaces).
- Prevents creating a tight loop by *sleeping* between the file-existence checks - adjust the sleep duration as desired; caveat: some platforms only support *integral* seconds.

---

If more robustness is desired, here's a version that:

- kills the background process via an exit trap, so as to ensure that it is killed, regardless of how the script itself exits (normally, or, say, via Control-C).
- exits the script if the background process is found to no longer be alive.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Set an exit trap to ensure that the tailing process
# - to be created below - is terminated, 
# no matter how this script exits.
trap '[[ -n $tailPid ]] && kill $tailPid 2>/dev/null' EXIT

# Start the tailing process in the background and
# record its PID.
tail -f "$1" & tailPid=$!

# Stay alive as long as the target file exists.
while [[ -f $1 ]]; do
  # Sleep a little.
  sleep 0.1
  # Exit if the tailing process died unexpectedly.
  kill -0 $tailPid 2>/dev/null || { tailPid=; exit; }
done
```

Comment: Cool. BTW, what does the `|| :` on the last line do?

Comment: @ToddLehman: it sets the `$tailPid` variable to the empty string and then exits, which triggers the `trap` handler, which - now that `$tailPid` no longer has a nonempty value (`-n`) - skips the no-longer-necessary `kill` call before exiting.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the last line of the *first* code block—specifically the `|| :` part. But thanks for the explanation for the last line of the second code block. :)

Comment: @ToddLehman: Oops! `|| :` ignores any failure reported by `kill`, by executing `:` when it does. The `:` builtin is an always-successful no-op, so that the exit code reported by the statement as a whole is guaranteed to be `0`. Resetting the exit code isn't strictly necessary, but if the statement happened to be the last one in a script, a failure of `kill` that you don't actually care about would be relayed as the script's exit code.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone else runs into this problem you can use a small script in which you run tail as a background process and then loop until the file is moved, killing the tail process.

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -f $1 &
pid=$!

while [ -f $1 ]
do
    if [ ! -f $1 ]
    then
        kill -9 $pid
    fi
done
```